# How do I call the value from another backed page form and use it on a component in OctoberCms

Tags: php, laravel, twig, backend, octobercms

I'm making a seo plugin and I'm also using the rainlab blog plugin, I have created a tab with fields where I can input the metas that I want to include in the head tag of the page but I don't know how to call the value from the form fields that are in the blog area (rainlab plugin menu tab) while my seo component is at a cms page I have tried to use the {{this.page.variable}}'method but since the input form is at another backend page it doesn't work.

This is how my plugin.php looks like:

```
<?php namespace Stronganswer\Seo;
use Backend;
use Event;
use System\Classes\PluginBase;
use Cms\Classes\Page;
use Cms\Classes\Theme;
use System\Classes\PluginManager;
use System\Classes\SettingsManager;

class Plugin extends PluginBase
{

    /**
     * Returns information about this plugin.
     *
     * @return array
     */
public function pluginDetails()
{
    return [
        'name'        => 'seo',
        'description' => 'meta and og tag handler',
        'author'      => 'stronganswer',
        'icon'        => 'icon-leaf'
    ];
}

/**
 * Registers any front-end components implemented in this plugin.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function registerComponents()
{

    return [
        'Stronganswer\Seo\Components\Seo' => 'seoHandler',
        'Stronganswer\Seo\Components\BlogPost' => 'SeoBlogPost',
        'Stronganswer\Seo\Components\StaticPage' => 'SeoStaticPage',
        'Stronganswer\Seo\Components\CmsPage' => 'SeoCmsPage',
    ];
}

public function registerSettings(){
    return [
        'settings' => [
            'label'       => 'SEO Settings',
            'description' => 'Seo Settings.',
            'icon'        => 'icon-bar-chart-o',
            'class'       => 'stronganswer\seo\Models\settings',
            'context'     => 'mysettings',
            'category'    =>  SettingsManager::CATEGORY_MYSETTINGS,
            'order'       => 1
        ]
    ];
}

/**
 * Registers any back-end permissions used by this plugin.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function registerPermissions()
{

    return [
        'stronganswer.seo.some_permission' => [
            'tab' => 'seo',
            'label' => 'Some permission'
        ],
    ];
}

/**
 * Registers back-end navigation items for this plugin.
 *
 * @return array
 */
  /*  public function registerNavigation()
{

    return [
        'seo' => [
            'label'       => 'seo',
            'url'         => Backend::url('stronganswer/seo/controllers'),
            'icon'        => 'icon-leaf',
            'permissions' => ['stronganswer.seo.*'],
            'order'       => 500,
        ],
    ];
}*/

public function boot()
{
  Event::listen('backend.form.extendFields', function($widget)
    {
      if(PluginManager::instance()->hasPlugin('RainLab.Pages') && $widget->model instanceof \RainLab\Pages\Classes\Page)
      { //static pages fields
        $widget->addFields([
          'viewBag[seo_title]' =>[
            'label' => 'Meta Title',
            'tab'     => 'SEO',
            'type' => 'text'
          ],
          'viewBag[seo_description]' =>[
            'label' => 'Meta Description',
            'tab'     => 'SEO',
            'size'    => 'tiny',
            'type' => 'textarea'
          ],
          'viewBag[seo_keywords]' =>[
            'label' => 'Meta Keywords',
            'tab'     => 'SEO',
            'type' => 'text'
          ],
          'viewBag[robot_index]' => [
            'label'   => 'Robot Index',
            'type'    => 'dropdown',
            'tab'     => 'SEO',
            'options' => ["index"=>"index","noindex"=>"noindex"],
            'default' => 'index',
            'span'    => 'left'
          ],
          'viewBag[robot_follow]' => [
            'label'   => 'Robot Follow',
            'type'    => 'dropdown',
            'tab'     => 'SEO',
            'options' => ["follow"=>"follow","nofollow"=>"nofollow"],
            'default' => 'follow',
            'span'    => 'right'
                    ]
        ], 'primary');
      }

      if(PluginManager::instance()->hasPlugin('RainLab.Blog') && $widget->model instanceof \RainLab\Blog\Models\Post)
      {
        $widget->addFields([
          'blog_title' =>[
            'label' => 'Meta Title',
            'tab' => 'Blog Seo',
            'type' => 'text'
          ],
          'seo_description' =>[
            'label' => 'Meta Description',
            'tab'     => 'Blog Seo',
            'size'    => 'tiny',
            'type' => 'textarea'
          ],
          'seo_keywords' =>[
            'label' => 'Meta Keywords',
            'tab'     => 'Blog Seo',
            'type' => 'text'
          ],
          'robot_index' => [
            'label'   => 'Robot Index',
            'type'    => 'dropdown',
            'tab'     => 'Blog Seo',
            'options' =>  ["index"=>"index","noindex"=>"noindex"],
            'default' => 'index',
            'span'    => 'left'
          ],
          'canonical_url' => [
                        'label'   => 'Canonical URL',
                        'type'    => 'text',
                        'tab'     => 'SEO',
                        'span'    => 'left'
                    ],
          'robot_follow' => [
            'label'   => 'Robot Follow',
            'type'    => 'dropdown',
            'tab'     => 'Blog Seo',
            'options' => ["follow"=>"follow","nofollow"=>"nofollow"],
            'default' => 'follow',
            'span'    => 'right'
                    ]
        ], 'secondary');
      }

      if (!$widget->model instanceof \Cms\Classes\Page) return;
      //cms page fields
                $widget->addFields([
                  'settings[seo_title]' =>[
                    'label' => 'Meta Title',
                    'tab'     => 'SEO',
                    'type' => 'text'
                  ],
                  'settings[seo_description]' =>[
                    'label' => 'Meta Description',
                    'tab'     => 'SEO',
                    'size'    => 'tiny',
                    'type' => 'textarea'
                  ],
                  'settings[seo_keywords]' =>[
                    'label' => 'Meta Keywords',
                    'tab'     => 'SEO',
                    'type' => 'text'
                  ],
                  'settings[robot_index]' => [
                    'label'   => 'Robot Index',
                    'type'    => 'dropdown',
                    'tab'     => 'SEO',
                    'options' => ["index"=>"index","noindex"=>"noindex"],
                    'default' => 'index',
                    'span'    => 'left'
                  ],
                  'settings[robot_follow]' => [
                    'label'   => 'Robot Follow',
                    'type'    => 'dropdown',
                    'tab'     => 'SEO',
                    'options' => ["follow"=>"follow","nofollow"=>"nofollow"],
                    'default' => 'follow',
                    'span'    => 'right'
                            ]
      ],  'primary');

           });

    }

}
```

and this is my component:

```
<?php namespace Stronganswer\Seo\Components;
use DB;
use Cms\Classes\ComponentBase;
use Stronganswer\Seo\models\Settings;
use RainLab\Pages\Classes\Router;
use RainLab\Blog\Models\Post;
use Cms\Classes\Theme;
use Cms\Classes\Page;
use Request;
use Event;

class BlogPost extends ComponentBase
{

  //singular page tags
public $page;
public $blog_title;
public $seo_title;
public $seo_description;
public $seo_keywords;
public $robot_index;
public $robot_follow;

//global tags
    public $ogTitle;
    public $ogDescription;
    public $ogSiteName;
    public $ogUrl;
    public $ogType;
    public $ogAuthor;
    public $ogImage;

//facebook tags
    public $ogFbAppId;
    public $ogFbAdmins;

//google tags
    public $ogGlTitle;
    public $ogGlDescription;
    public $ogGlImage;

//twitter tags
    public $ogTtCard;
    public $ogTtSite;
    public $ogTtTitle;
    public $ogTtDescription;
    public $ogTtAuthor;
    public $ogTtImage;

public function componentDetails()
{
    return [
        'name'        => 'Seo BlogPost component',
        'description' => 'handles seo fields into blogposts'
    ];
}

public function defineProperties()
{
    return [
        "post" => [
                "title" => "data",
                "default" => "post"
        ]
    ];
}

public function Run()
{
  $theme = Theme::getActiveTheme();
  $page = Page::load($theme,$this->page->baseFileName);
  $this->page["hasBlog"] = true;

  if($page->hasComponent("blogPost"))
  {
  //$seo = DB::table('rainlab_blog_posts')->get();

  //$blog_title = DB::table('rainlab_blog_posts')->where('slug','=','first-blog-post')->value('seo_title');

  //$this->seo_title = $this->page['blog_title'] = $this->page->getViewBag()->property('blog_title');
  //$this->seo_title = $this->page["seo_title"] = $this->page->seo_title;
  /*$blog_title = DB::table('rainlab_blog_posts')
                       ->select(DB::raw('select seo_title'))
                       ->where('slug', '=', 'first-blog-post')
                       ->get();*/

  $this->seo_description = $this->page["seo_description"] = $this->page->meta_description;
  $this->seo_keywords = $this->page["seo_keywords"] = $this->page->seo_keywords;
  $this->robot_follow = $this->page["robot_follow"] = $this->page->robot_follow;
  $this->robot_index = $this->page["robot_index"] = $this->page->robot_index;

  $settings = Settings::instance();

      if($settings->enable_og_tags)
      {
          $this->ogTitle = $settings->og_title;
          $this->ogDescription = $settings->og_description;
          $this->ogSiteName = $settings->og_sitename;
          $this->ogUrl = $settings->og_url;
          $this->ogType = $settings->og_type;
          $this->ogAuthor = $settings->og_author;
          $this->ogImage = $settings->og_img;
      }

      if($settings->enable_fb_tags)
      {
          $this->ogFbAppId = $settings->og_fb_appid;
          $this->ogFbAdmins = $settings->og_fb_admins;
      }

      if($settings->enable_ggl_tags)
      {
        $this->ogGlTitle = $settings->og_gl_title;
        $this->ogGlDescription = $settings->og_gl_description;
        $this->ogGlImage = $settings->og_gl_img;
      }

      if($settings->enable_tt_tags)
      {
         $this->ogTtCard = $settings->og_tt_card;
         $this->ogTtSite = $settings->og_tt_site;
         $this->ogTtTitle = $settings->og_tt_title;
         $this->ogTtDescription = $settings->og_tt_description;
         $this->ogTtAuthor = $settings->og_tt_author;
         $this->ogTtImage = $settings->og_tt_img;
      }

}
  else{
  $this->hasBlog = $this->page["hasBlog"] = false;
  }

}
}
```

The code within the comments are failed trys to get the values from the form. If I go to my database I can see the values that I inputed in the form but I can't call them to my component.

and my deafult.htm :

```
<meta name="title" content="{{__SELF__.blog_title}}">

  <meta name="description" content="{{__SELF__.seo_description}}">

  <meta name="keywords" content="{{__SELF__.seo_keywords}}">

  <meta name="robots" content="{{__SELF__.robot_index}},{{__SELF__.robot_follow}}">

  <meta property="og:site_name" content="{{ __SELF__.ogSiteName }}" />

  <meta property="og:title" content="{{ __SELF__.ogTitle }}" />

  <meta property="og:url" content="{{ __SELF__.ogUrl }}" />

  <meta property="og:description" content="{{ __SELF__.ogDescription }}" />

  <meta property="og:type" content="{{ __SELF__.ogType }}" />

  <meta name="author" content="{{ __SELF__.ogAuthor }}" />

  <meta property="og:image" content="{{ __SELF__.ogImage }}" />

  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="{{ __SELF__.ogFbAppId  }}" />

  <meta property="fb:admins" content="{{ __SELF__.ogFbAdmins  }}" />

  <meta itemprop="name" content="{{ __SELF__.ogGlTitle  }}" />

  <meta itemprop="description" content="{{ __SELF__.ogGlDescription  }}" />

  <meta itemprop="image" content="{{ __SELF__.ogGlImage  }}" />

  <meta itemprop="image" content="{{ __SELF__.ogGlImage  }}" />

  <meta name="twitter:card" content="{{__SELF__.ogTtCard}}">

  <meta name="twitter:site" content="{{__SELF__.ogTtSite}}">

  <meta name="twitter:title" content="{{__SELF__.ogTtTitle}}">

  <meta name="twitter:description" content="{{__SELF__.ogTtDescription}}">

  <meta name="twitter:creator" content="{{__SELF__.ogTtAuthor}}">

  <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="{{__SELF__.ogTtImage}}">
```

I also have forms for cms pages and for the rainlab pages plugin(static pages) I get them from another components that I have made and I wanted to point out that both of them are working fine.

Comment: Try changing function `Run` in Component to `onRun` and then simply assign static value to blog_title e.g. `$this->blog_title = 'Some Title';` and see does it work or not.

Comment: thanks for spotting that error I allready fixed it. The static value appears on the output of the page code but I still don't know how to call it from the other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call the value from the DB I did like this:

Insert this into the component onRun fucntion:

```
$this->blog_seo_or_smth = DB::table('rainlab_blog_posts')->where('slug','first-blog-post')->first();
```

Then on the default.htm:

```
<meta name="title" content="{{__SELF__.blog_seo_or_smth.seo_title}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm also working to understand how to extend field in cmsPages and rainlabPages simultaneoulsy and then use a partial to print fileds in my html source.
So i create this partial:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" >
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="{{ this.page.meta_description }}">

<meta name="robots" content=",">
<meta property="og:title" content="October - {{ this.page.title }}" />
<meta property="og:url" content="{{ this.page.url }}" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="{{ title }}" />
<meta property="og:description" content="{{ this.page.meta_description }}" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="xxx" />
<meta property="og:type" content="xxx">
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ this.theme.site_logo_url }}">
<meta name="twitter:card" content="{{ summary }}">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="October- {{ this.page.title }}">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="{{ this.page.meta_description }}">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="{{ this.theme.site_logo_url }}">
```

I think the best solution is: create a plugin that extends fields of cmsPages and rainLab Pages than print with a partial!
Look into the code of seoextension by anandpatel maybe could help but i'm not very strong in coding so we can help each other.

I think the function is:

```
   public function register()
{

    \Event::listen('backend.form.extendFields', function($widget)
    {

        if(PluginManager::instance()->hasPlugin('RainLab.Pages') && $widget->model instanceof \RainLab\Pages\Classes\Page)
        {

            if (!$widget->model instanceof \Cms\Classes\Page) return;

        if (!($theme = Theme::getEditTheme())) {
            throw new ApplicationException(Lang::get('cms::lang.theme.edit.not_found'));
```

Maybe we can insert this project to git.

Bye
Gabriele

Answer (score 0):

If you need values from a form use the `Input` class

https://octobercms.com/docs/services/request-input

> You may access all user input with a few simple methods. You do not need to worry about the HTTP verb for the request when using the Input facade, as input is accessed in the same way for all verbs. The global input() helper function is an alias for Input::get.
>
> Retrieving an input value

```
$name = Input::get('name');
```

> Retrieving a default value if the input value is absent

```
$name = Input::get('name', 'Sally');
```

> Determining if an input value is present

```
if (Input::has('name')) {
    //
}
```

But i'm thinking you're meaning something else, but i'm not sure, because the actual question isn't clear.

There are a lot of things to consider when extending a plugin you should check in these cases:

- Do my fields get created in the database?
- Do my values get saved in the database?
- Should I use a relationship on those items instead of modifying those items
- Can I `dd($somevalue)` the values in my components(dd kills any execution and dumps the variables. very useful to analyze them)
- Do I have a seperate management model and controller to manage my values for debugging purposes. what do those show?
- Can I access the values directly by query?
- are my component settings configured/registered correctly?
- What bugs are traced in Settings/Event log

To debug october can be a pain when starting out, but once you get the hang of it it's fun :-)

Comment: ok in other words my problem is that I have a backend page that I called blog at the cms menu tab (../backend/cms) but I'm using the RainLab Blog plugin and that plugin gives me a new tab (../backend/rainlab/blog/posts) and I gave that plugin a extra form and I want to get that form values and I only know the this->page method but that way I can only get the cms values(../backend/cms)[note: I also have a extra form in the cms page and all the forms I'm talking about are backend forms not frontend].
I hope this time I was more clear.

Comment: the fields get created in Database , and also the values I did a query in my db and it returns the value I will try now using the dd comand I also tried something similar before I used in my default.htm the {{dump(blog_title)}} and it returned null, I'm really newbie in october and laravel.

Comment: Do the dd part in the php segment of your partial. more helpfull that way. You can also do the dd part in your component php. Also consider posting this question to http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97119/octobercms and upvoting the questions that still have to reach 10 or are nearly there. don't upvote questions above 10

Comment: ok it returns Null, I'm trying to get the $blog_title value I just don't know the code how to get it from db (I'm using workbench) when I go to workbench and do there a query it returns the blog_title value properly but how do I get it inside my component ??

Comment: do a dump of your page model. it might be something like `{{page.blog_title}}` or in php `$page->blog_title`. Doing a `dd(get_declared_vars)` also might help a bit

Comment: the database field that I want to get is called 'seo_title' I think that dumping vars will allways return null because I don't call the the value from DB my issue is that I don't know how to call it.

Comment: You have the page object right? just dump the page object. you're extending the page and blogpost objects, so your fields will be in those. like page.seo_title or blogpost.seo_title...

Comment: I don't know how to get the object of another backend menu zone

Comment: ok I solved the problem I just didn't exacute properly the query and also was calling it in the default.htm wrong thank you for the help <3

Comment: Please consider self answering your question to help future octobercms question seekers